# Copy data between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I have code that copies data from Sheet1 in Workbook1 to Sheet2 in Workbook2:

```
Sub Copydata()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User1\Documents\Workbook1.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User1\Documents\Workbook2.xlsx")
With x.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    y.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize( _
        .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With
x.Close
y.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

This code works fine and copies the data only if workbook2 is closed. If I run this code from workbook2 by opening the file, the results won't be copied to this workbook.

Can't we copy results to the opened workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually setting the workbook2 as active workbook helped.

```
 Set y = Application.ActiveWorkbook
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so if the workbooks are opened in the same application shell. instead of

`set x = workbooks.open("C:\Users\User1\Documents\Workbook1.xlsx")`

use

`set x = workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made the change you suggested and it is throwing an error 'subscript out of range'